# в чем разница между двумя функциями

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T> struct A
{
   A<T> foo (A<T>, A<T>) {return A<T>();}
   A foo (A,A) {return A();}
};
```

В чём разница между 2 функциями?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разницы, как таковой, нет. Просто в одном случае шаблонный класс явно параметризован типом `T`, а в другом - неявно. В этом можно убедиться на соответствующем примере:

```
template <typename T> 
struct A
{
   A<T> foo (A<T>, A<T>) {return A<T>();}
   A foo (A,A) {return A();}
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    a.foo(a,a);
}
```

При [компиляции](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/15la29F6oo2PngLb) будет выведена ошибка:

> error: class member cannot be redeclared

Т.е. компилятор посчитал функции идентичными.

При этом использование краткого имени в данном случае предпочтительнее, т.к. не зависит от изменения имени шаблонного параметра или их кол-ва.

---

В Стандарте языка данный момент описан в п.[14.6.1/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#1):

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). [...] is equivalent
>   to the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>.